# MYSQL specific SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm sorry but I don't know how to specify my problem in the correct words (this is why I don't know what to put into google or look up in the mysql-doc). I try to simplify and describe my problem here. I guess the solution is quied easy but I can not find it.

I have two tables. The first only contains some persons.

```
| id | name    | lastname   | age | size |
| 1  | 'max'   | 'foo'      | 12  | 156  |
| 2  | 'john'  | 'bar'      | 20  | 191  |
| 3  | 'jane'  | 'doe'      | 17  | 175  |
```

and the second describes who is giving whom a gift. (this example came just out of my mind to make it clear, what my problem is)

```
| id | gift_description | from_kid | to_kid | price |
| 1  | 'bow and arrow'  | 2        | 1  | 40$   |
| 2  | 'rc car'         | 3        | 2  | 20$   |
| 3  | 'baby doll'      | 1        | 3  | 5$    |
```

Now I'm looking for a SELECT-Statement which gives me the names of the kids like:

```
| id | kid_a | kid_b | gift_description |
| 1  | john  | max   | 'bow and arrow'  | 
| 2  | jane  | john  | 'rc car'         |
| 3  | max   | jane  | 'baby_doll'      |
```

I tried something like:

```
SELECT id, gift_description, name AS kid_a, name AS kid_b 
FROM TABLE gifts, persons
WHERE (gifts.from_kid = persons.name 
     AND gifts.to_kid = persons.name);
```

Of course this can not work, but I'm missing the last piece. (As far you can easily see, I'm not very comfortable with MYSQL).

Comment: You don't actually store '$', do you?

Comment: The good news is: this isn't actually MySQL-specific. It would be the same query for other DBMS. Escaping `from` and `to` are the only really specific things.

Comment: @Strawberry: no of course I don't. This is just the simpliest example which came to my mind ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do this with a join, actually two joins:

```
select t2.id, tfrom.name as kid_a, tto.name as kid_b, t2.gift_description
from secondtable t2 join
     firsttable tfrom
     on t2.`from` = t1.id join
     firsttable tto
     on t2.`to` = t2.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, what you were looking for was `JOIN` statement

```
SELECT G.id, p.name AS kid_a, P1.name AS kid_b, gift_description 
FROM persons P 
INNER JOIN gifts G ON G.from_kid  = P.ID
INNER JOIN persons P1 ON P1.ID = G.to_kid
```